# mobile chrome browser fetch is not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, next.js, mobile

I made simple get fetch in nextjs,
It is good working pc chrome browser and mobile other browser.
but It is always return "fail" in chrome "mobile" browser.

```
"use client";

const Fcm = () => {
    const testHandler = async () => {
        // http://10.10.10.214:8080/api/test/dest return just "test" string
        const resp = await fetch("http://10.10.10.214:8080/api/test/dest", {
            method: "GET",
        })
            .then((resp) => {
                alert("success");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert("fail");
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>
            <button onClick={testHandler}>test</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Fcm;
```